# How to call a function defined in Xamarin.Droid, in the Xamarin.Forms project?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

There is a Shared Project solution.

How to call the function defined in the project for Android from the main project?

For example, the function that runs the background task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about dependency injection and inversion of control. Then you can use this one:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

to register implementation of your contract, then resolve it from the Core project and invoke.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the worst way to do this but if its just a single task you are trying to call it will work just fine...

```
public partial class App : Application
{
          public static Action<byte[]> playBack;
}
```

If you add a static option to your Application class you should be able to reference it from anywhere in your code.

Then in your Android code you attach the platform specific implementation to the Action.

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());

        MyApp.App.playBack += MyCrazyAction;
    }

    public void MyCrazyAction(byte[] array)
    {
        //doing stuff to this byte array

    }
```

In a perfect world you would wrap this functionality with an Interface